# How to sort by collection helper field with meteor reactive table

Tags: collections, meteor

If you set up [reactive-table](https://atmospherejs.com/package/reactive-table) with [collection helpers](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers), you can't sort on the collection helper field. How can you do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the function field, add a reflexive function:

```
'fn': function(val, obj){ return val;}
```

Comment: is this a helper? What is val and obj here? Could you be more elaborative?